# Getting text from browser window with c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the text from a specific area of the browser window. 
I've tried getting the html file , and then parsing it , but its an absolute nightmare . 
And the data expands , so I need to download a new version of the html file very often , which is slow. Considering that I know exactly where the text i need is situated on the window , is there a way to get it , without having to go through cURL? I was thinking maybe if i copy that specific area , and then access the clipboard , but that seems unsafe and tedious .

Comment: as much as I'm C++ advocator myself, currently there is no right tool for that in C++. Selenium driver is much more suitable for this task and you can write in many programning languges to that driver

Comment: Are you friends with the guy who asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253732/)? Both of you seem to be trying to do similar things. Parsing HTML is only an "absolute nightmare" if you're writing the code to do it yourself. It's rather simple if you use one of the existing libraries designed to do exactly that. And I'm not sure what you mean about "as the data expands, so I need to download a new version of the HTML file." I mean, yeah, I guess that's true, but scraping it from the browser isn't going to change that. You'll still need to reload to get any new changes.

Comment: No , i don't know the guy , although i can see some similarity in what we're trying to achieve  . I want to get some data from facebook , but using libcurl won't work because it just gives the data from the login page of facebook , and not my actual (logged in) page . So instead i tried downloading the page automatically , by moving the mouse to download page source , and then saving it. This works , but i don't need to explain why its awful . So now i'm trying to scrape the screen .

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery like library for parsing HTML - https://github.com/lazytiger/gumbo-query . Accessing browser' Window is tedious and will require more details about the actual OS and browser, since their inner details are vastly different - as a result it won't be as easy as figuring out how to use GetWindowHandle and GetWindowText